# "SMTP connect() failed". When configuring it to send emails from remote Host

Tags: php, email, smtp, xampp

I am new at PHP. I am using PHPMailer to send emails but unable to do so. I tried configuring it for gmail and it worked But not working when tried to send msg from remote host and for the given domain.
Here is the code.

```
<?php  

       require("PHPMailerAutoload.php"); // path to the PHPMailerAutoload.php file.

       $mail = new PHPMailer();
       //$mail->IsSMTP();
       $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
       $mail->Host = "175.000.000.000"; //Sample Host
       $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
       $mail->Port = "25"; // 8025, 587 and 25 can also be used. Use Port 465 for SSL.
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
       $mail->Username = "maaz@mcbah.com";
       $mail->Password = "password";

       $mail->From     = "maaz@mcbah.com";
       $mail->FromName = "Maaz Khan";
       $mail->AddAddress("mcbah.all@mcbah.com", "all");
       $mail->AddReplyTo("fundprices@mcbah.com", "Fund");

       $mail->Subject  = "Hi!";
       $mail->Body     = "Hi! How are you?";
       $mail->WordWrap = 50;  

       if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo 'Message was not sent.';
            echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    echo 'Not sent: <pre>'.print_r(error_get_last(), true).'</pre>';
            exit;
       } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent.';
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

> $mail->Host     = "smtpout.secureserver.net";

```
Your host name should be like mydomain.com
```

> $mail->Port = 465;